# How to convert a date-time into string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a date as follows.

```
$discount_start_date='03/27/2012 18:47';

$start_date=new DateTime($discount_start_date);
$start_date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

How can I convert it to a string in PHP so that it can be stored into MySql? I'm from Java background and very new to PHP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `DateTime`.  The normal php way of doing this sort of thing is to use `date()` and `strtotime()`;

```
$discount_start_date = '03/27/2012 18:47';    
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($discount_start_date));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to convert it into a string. MySQL has a date, time, datetime, as well as timestamp native data types. You should be able to simply insert the date immediately without casting it to a string so long as you insert it into one of these fields and have it formatted properly.

Comment: How can I insert the date stored in `$start_date` into MySql `DateTime` field?